# Running old JDK/JVM versions in a modern Linux environment

Tags: linux, jvm, glibc, strace, binary-compatibility

I'm trying to run an old JDK (version **1.3** released in May 2000) in a relatively modern Linux box (Debian 10).

As far as binary compatibility is concerned, everything seems fine, since all the necessary 32-bit dependencies are still available in Debian Linux:

- `libbsd0`
- `libc6`
- `libgcc1`
- `libice6`
- `libnspr4`
- `libodbc1`
- `libsm6`
- `libuuid1`
- `libx11-6`
- `libxau6`
- `libxcb1`
- `libxdmcp6`
- `libxext6`
- `libxi6`
- `libxt6`
- `libxtst6`
- `unixodbc-dev`

What's missing is `libxp6:i386` which is luckily still available from [Debian 8 "Jessie"](https://www.debian.org/releases/jessie/) and the ancient `libstdc++` from gcc **2.96**, which can be taken from early CentOS versions (CentOS 4, `compat-libstdc++-296` package).

Using the above recipé, I used to successfully run Java **1.3** (incl. even the JDBC-ODBC bridge) up until Debian 9. Then, Debian 10 was released. Now, running `java -version` instead of the usual

```
java version "1.3.1_20"
Java(TM) 2 Runtime Environment, Standard Edition (build 1.3.1_20-b03)
Java HotSpot(TM) Client VM (build 1.3.1_20-b03, mixed mode)
```

prints out

```
Error occurred during initialization of VM
java/lang/NoClassDefFoundError: java/lang/Object
```

Indeed, it fails to unpack `rt.jar` and load `java/lang/Object.class` out of the JAR archive. When running `strace -f`, the difference between Debian 9 and Debian 10 can be clearly seen. Here, the process opens `rt.jar` and maps it (`mmap()`) into the virtual memory:

```c
stat64("/usr/lib/jvm/java-1.3.1_20-sun-i386/jre/lib/rt.jar", {st_mode=S_IFREG|0644, st_size=13904932, ...}) = 0
lstat64("/usr", {st_mode=S_IFDIR|0755, st_size=4096, ...}) = 0
lstat64("/usr/lib", {st_mode=S_IFDIR|0755, st_size=4096, ...}) = 0
lstat64("/usr/lib/jvm", {st_mode=S_IFDIR|0755, st_size=4096, ...}) = 0
lstat64("/usr/lib/jvm/java-1.3.1_20-sun-i386", {st_mode=S_IFDIR|0775, st_size=4096, ...}) = 0
lstat64("/usr/lib/jvm/java-1.3.1_20-sun-i386/jre", {st_mode=S_IFDIR|0775, st_size=4096, ...}) = 0
lstat64("/usr/lib/jvm/java-1.3.1_20-sun-i386/jre/lib", {st_mode=S_IFDIR|0775, st_size=4096, ...}) = 0
lstat64("/usr/lib/jvm/java-1.3.1_20-sun-i386/jre/lib/rt.jar", {st_mode=S_IFREG|0664, st_size=13904932, ...}) = 0
open("/usr/lib/jvm/java-1.3.1_20-sun-i386/jre/lib/rt.jar", O_RDONLY|O_LARGEFILE) = 3
fstat64(3, {st_mode=S_IFREG|0664, st_size=13904932, ...}) = 0
_llseek(3, 0, [13904932], SEEK_END)     = 0
mmap2(NULL, 13904932, PROT_READ, MAP_SHARED, 3, 0) = 0xf6b9c000
close(3)                                = 0
```

And here's exactly the same scenario from Debian 10:

```c
stat64("/usr/lib/jvm/java-1.3.1_20-sun-i386/jre/lib/rt.jar", {st_mode=S_IFREG|0644, st_size=13904932, ...}) = 0
openat(AT_FDCWD, "/usr/lib/jvm/java-1.3.1_20-sun-i386/jre", O_RDONLY|O_LARGEFILE) = 3
fstat64(3, {st_mode=S_IFDIR|0775, st_size=4096, ...}) = 0
close(3)                                = 0
```

As you can see, instead of `/usr/lib/jvm/java-1.3.1_20-sun-i386/jre/lib/rt.jar` being opened (`open()` or `openat()`), one of its parent directories (`/usr/lib/jvm/java-1.3.1_20-sun-i386/jre`) is opened, quite expectedly resulting in the empty JVM classpath.

The cause of the problem is definitely not the kernel: I observe the same difference using `i386/debian:10` vs `i386/debian:9` Docker image with exactly the same kernel on exactly the same hardware.

The workarounds I'm considering are:

- using a VM with an earlier Linux version,
- using a Docker container with an earlier Linux userspace,
- substituting an earlier `glibc` version,
- switching to any BSD UNIX (Free/Net/DragonFly), with a stable Linux ABI.

Still, are there any ways to further diagnose the problem?

Comment: Out of sheer curiosity - why are you trying to run a 23 year old java?

Comment: @tink I'm into retrocomputing. In this particular case, I want to run NetBeans 3.0 IDE using the period-correct JVM.

Comment: In that case - opinion based, from a sysadmins experience set - I'd strongly suggest not to retrofit cruft onto your main OS and go with a VM of sorts. KVM, VirtualBox, VMware Desktop, Bochs ... whatever floats your boat.

Comment: @tink Thank you! That's what I was considering myself — yet I need some time to accept the inevitable.

Comment: And another tangential note: **relatively modern Linux** ... buster has gone EOL **2022-08-14** ;) Did I mention that I have a sysadmin mindset (and a fairly strong security focus)? ;D